# Adding a list of strings to an existing key in a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to add strings to a list(adding new strings in each loop with .append()), after that adding the list to an existing key. The problem is after adding the new string to the list and than to a key in console get printed [...](how to get rid of this [...]) example:

```
x = {}
y = ["going home"]
x["key"].append(y)
y.append("after lunch")
x["key"].append(y)
print(x)
{'key' : ['going home', 'after lunch', [...]]}
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Probably missing: `x["key"] = []` to be reproducible.

Comment: What's the problem/error? See [mcve]

Comment: also take care to distinguish `append` vs. `extend` when you add lists to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the correct behavior is:

```
x = {}
y = ["going home"]
x["key"] = y
y.append("after lunch")
print(x)
```

```
{'key': ['going home', 'after lunch']}
```